# Is it safe to install brave from AUR?

Tags: arch-linux, chrome, browser, aur

I'm planning to switch to ArcoLinux but I use brave and I was a little bit worried about having to install a program that is maintained by some random person that might corrupt the package itself. Is this even possible?

Comment: is *what* even possible?

Comment: OP fear that guys packaging `brave` put some backdoors or malicious software @MarcusMüller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AUR` is close to be more easy to review than binary you install via `pacman`.

Just take a look to the [`PKGBUILD`](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=brave)

All is open source and listed, and there's some checksums.

The `PKGBUILD` is just a helper script to avoid you to compile it manually.

As far as it's a big and complex project, the `PKGBUILD` helps a lot here.

IMHO, it's safe to use, if you are not sure take the time to review each link.

If you think it's too risky or too much work for you, consider using a more mainstream distro like `Ubuntu` or `LinuxMint`. It's less bleeding edge, but if you don't use too many PPAs, all is relatively safe and you can install [the Brave Snap](https://snapcraft.io/brave) or even better, use [`apt` Brave's repository](https://brave.com/linux/).