# Is it safe to install brave for AUR?

Tags: arch-linux, chrome, browser, aur

I've always used either windows, macOS or linux distros that have brave to be downloaded through official means, but now I'm planning to switch to arch linux and I'll have to download it from the AUR.

I checked online and apparently brave is only available through the AUR in arch based distros, so I was wondering if it is safe to use it although it is maintained by common users.

Comment: Is this different to your [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/743133/22222)?

Comment: Also, you know you can always download from the Brave website, just like you would on Windows, and install from source, right? It's usually not worth the effort.

Comment: @terdon for Brave specifically building from source isn’t quite the same as downloading a ready-made binary: the binaries Brave provides embed their API keys which are required to access some of the features in Brave (ad-blocking etc.). That’s why many distributions don’t provide a Brave package directly.

Comment: @StephenKitt didn't know that, but I'm a bit surprised that you couldn't do a reproducible source build to check whether what you're getting from your browser vendor. That would directly contradict the whole premise of brave in that it's the more trustworthy browser. Interesting!

Comment: @MarcusMüller see [this upstream discussion](https://community.brave.com/t/does-brave-allow-the-distribution-of-self-compiled-or-distro-compiled-binaries/457833/10) for details. Brave [isn’t reproducible yet](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/5830).

Comment: @StephenKitt that's highly interesting, on multiple levels. I do not fully concur with Brave's reasoning there (the costly services used by their build cost exactly the same as they would cost to be run from, say, an arch or debian build of the same source – and it's not like they could hide the keys in a binary whose source code they promise to deliver, licensewise, anyways. But I see the organisatorial and technical challenges of keeping secrets and code separate.

Answer (score 0):

> apparently brave is only available through the AUR in arch based distros

No, Brave is also available through [Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.brave.Browser) or as [a Snap](https://snapcraft.io/brave), and both can be installed on Arch-based distributions (`flatpak` is available in the distribution; installing Snap requires trusting AUR for `snapd`). The binaries available in this fashion are produced by Brave themselves.